# How to create a log in page w/o navbar and the landing page w/ navbar?

Tags: reactjs

i dont want a navbar in my log in page

```
render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div style={{position:'fixed', width: '100%'}}>  
        <NavBar />
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/LogIn" component={LogIn}  exact />
            <Route path="/Home" component={Home}  exact />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}  exact />
            <Route path="/mapview" component={MapView}  exact />
            <Route path="/faq" component={FAQ}  exact />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXdO7.png)

Comment: You can check if the current URL =="/login" with window.location.href .If it is then hide Navbar.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not require `Navbar` in `Login`, `Signup` pages, just move the component with `Navbar` out of the component that these routes are defined in. For example:

In main `App` component file:

```
render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div style={{position:'fixed', width: '100%'}}>  
          <Route exact path="/LogIn" component={LogIn} />
          <Route path="/" component={Content} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

In component `Content` file:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>  
        <NavBar />
         <Switch>
            <Route path="/Home" component={Home}  exact />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}  exact />
            <Route path="/mapview" component={MapView}  exact />
            <Route path="/faq" component={FAQ}  exact />
         </Switch>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: the content file is the landing page? what im trying to do is...the log in page will not have a navbar and then when i click signup button it redirect to landing page with navbar...thank you for your time for this...

Comment: content could be the landing page, yes. But it seems like you have made a homepage with `home`. In this, only `Content` has `Navbar`, `Login` as it is outside goes not have it